# jQuery Draggable, Droppable query

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm looking to build a web application similar to the game of the Fox, Chicken and Oats. The riddle where you need to get each across a river but can't leave some items together.
[Fox, Chicken, Oats](https://riddlesbrainteasers.com/fox-chicken-sack-grain/)

So I am trying to drag for example the chicken first (pink square to blue square), then drag the fox (red-square) to blue and take back the chicken (pink) drop the pink square and bring the oats (yellow) over to the blue. So I need an alert if for example the red/pink end up alone on the same side and same with the pink/yellow.

Here is my code so far:

```
    <body>
<div id="red-square">Fox</div>
<div id="blue-square">Other Side</div>
<div id="yellow-square">Oats</div>
<div id="pink-square">Chicken</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#red-square").draggable();
    $("#pink-circle").draggable();
    $("#yellow-square").draggable();
    $("#blue-square").droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
        alert("No");

    }

    });     

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Have you checked events? : https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events
Sounds like what you are looking for is the 'stop' event. Have a look at the example, try to implement your own logic.

Edit: Check also, 'drop' event of droppable.

Comment: I see that but I'm sure I need an IF statement if a particular square is dragged first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For draggable, you want to revert if the drop returns a `false` value. For example:

```js
$(function() {
  function findFox() {
    var $items = $(".house").find(".piece");
    var fox = false;
    if ($items) {
      $items.each(function(i, el) {
        if ($(el).hasClass("fox")) {
          console.log("Fox Found.");
          fox = true;
        }
      });
    }
    return fox;
  }
  $(".piece").draggable({
    revert: true
  });
  $("#blue-square").droppable({
    accept: ".piece",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var $drag = ui.draggable;
      var fox = false;
      if ($drag.hasClass("chicken")) {
        fox = findFox();
      }
      if (fox) {
        return false;
      } else {
        $drag.attr("style", "")
          .appendTo($(this));
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.piece {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 1.5em 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.house {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em;
  height: 3em;
}

.house .title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.red {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .35);
}

.blue {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .35);
}

.yellow {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, .35);
}

.pink {
  border: 1px solid pink;
  background: rgba(170, 0, 20, .35);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="red-square" class="red fox piece">Fox</div>
<div id="blue-square" class="blue house">
  <span class="title">Other Side</span>
</div>
<div id="yellow-square" class="yellow oat piece">Oats</div>
<div id="pink-square" class="pink chicken piece">Chicken</div>
```

There is more to do, but this can help explain the basics.

Comment: A much more flushed out and complex example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ogo7gbb6/1/

Comment: I'm looking at your first post, it looks to be what I need. Would the idea now be to have another IF statement 
if ($drag.hasClass("chicken")) {
        fox = findFox();
      }
      if (fox) {
        return false;

and use if has class"Oats", chicken= findChicken, if chicken, return false?

Comment: @conye9980 you can create various functions like `findFox()`, `findChicken()`, and `findGrain()`. It's up to you. If they each return `true` or `false`, then you can use them with IF statement much like I did in the first example.

Comment: Thanks Twisty. A great help!